# Stanford NLP GrammaticalRelation Types?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Soo... The program works exactly how it should, but I do not understand what the fancy abbreviations that the program outputs.

If I input 'I wish today was a school day', the program will output

```
I/PRP : wish/VBP : nsubj
wish/VBP : day/NN : csubj
today/NN : wish/VBP : nmod:tmod
was/VBD : day/NN : cop
a/DT : day/NN : det
school/NN : day/NN : compound
day/NN : ROOT : root
```

I just want to know what the 'cop', 'det', 'nsubj', 'csubj', etc stuff is; so that I can understand the relations between these words.

```
String modelPath = null;
String taggerPath = null;
MaxentTagger tagger = null;
DependencyParser parser = null;
Properties props;
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

public ConversationEngine() {
    modelPath = DependencyParser.DEFAULT_MODEL;
    taggerPath = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger";
    tagger = new MaxentTagger(taggerPath);
    parser = DependencyParser.loadFromModelFile(modelPath);
    props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
}

public void parseSentence(String text) {
    String subject = "";
    DocumentPreprocessor tokenizer = new DocumentPreprocessor(new StringReader(text));
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : tokenizer) {
        List<TaggedWord> tagged = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
        GrammaticalStructure gs = parser.predict(tagged);
        for (TypedDependency dep : gs.typedDependenciesEnhancedPlusPlus()) {
            System.out.println(dep.dep() + " : " + dep.gov() + " : " + dep.reln());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `dep.reln().toPrettyString()` (see [GrammaticalRelation#toPrettyString](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalRelation.html#toPrettyString--))

When you call `dep.reln()` inside of the `println` this is implied as `dep.reln().toString()` and the javadocs state that this

> Returns short name (abbreviation) for this GrammaticalRelation.

(see [GrammaticalRelation#toString](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalRelation.html#toString--))